# Why does my Sudoku Solver program not work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a simple Sudoku Solver. Two of my three functions don't seem to be working as expected, and I can't understand why. Can someone take a look at my (not clean, I know) code, so that I can finish this project? Thanks in advance :)

```
tabela = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

subtract = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
numeros = list()
numeros1 = list()
linha = list()
coluna = list()
vals_poss = list()
h = 0
```

## I have a portion of code here that inputs values for the board (tabela).

## this function checks the row for possible values, seems to work.

```
def checkLinha(j, k):
    return [x for x in subtract if x not in tabela[j]]
```

## this function checks the column for possible values, does not seem to work.

```
def checkColuna(j, k):
    for i in range(9):
        numeros.append(tabela[i][k])
    return [x for x in subtract if x not in numeros]
```

## this function checks the square, does not seem to work.

```
def checkQuadrado(j, k):
    global linha, coluna
    primeiro = [0, 1, 2]
    segundo = [3, 4, 5]
    terceiro = [6, 7, 8]
    encontrar_quadrado = [primeiro, segundo, terceiro]
    for l in encontrar_quadrado:
        if j in l:
            linha = l
        if k in l:
            coluna = l
    for x in linha:
        for y in coluna:
            numeros1.append(tabela[x][y])
    return [x for x in subtract if x not in numeros1]
```

## this function crosses the results from the three funcions defined before.

```
def get_valores_possiveis(i, j):
    return set(checkLinha(i, j)).intersection(checkColuna(i, j), 
    checkQuadrado(i, j))
```

## this function uses the function before to find cells that only have one possible value.

```
def explicit_solver():
    global vals_poss
    for i in range(0, 9):
        for j in range(0, 9):
            if tabela[i][j] == '0':
                vals_poss = get_valores_possiveis(i, j)
                if len(vals_poss) == 1:
                    tabela[i][j] = list(vals_poss)[0]
```

My checkLinha() funtion works as expected, but both the checkColuna() and checkQuadrado() don't seem to do it.

Comment: Why don't you use a class? Sudoku seems perfectly suited for it.

Comment: If all the functions belong together, why not using a single easy to copy code block? What about translating the name of the variables to English? It will make your code more easily accessible to a wider audience.